# PowerShell: Pipe contents of csv file in to custom function

Tags: powershell, csv, import

I have a custom POWERSHELL function that needs to accept array of data coming from a csv file (preferably another cmdlet that produces this CSV), read the contents and then generate some desired output based on a comparison. the comparison portion works as desired but only when I hardcode the import-csv ComputerServicesList line inside the function. For flexability, I need the function ot accept this as a parameter. Below is my current funtion. I am out of ideas on what to try at this point.

```
function myTest3 {
    [cmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,
                   HelpMessage="Input a CSV vile with at least the follwoing cols: ComputerName, ServiceName, State")]    
        [array]$InputData 
    )

    #$data = $InputData
    $report= @()
    $counter = 0
    foreach ($line in $InputData) {
        $tempreport = New-Object PSObject
        $tempreport | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ComputerName -value $line.computerName
        $tempreport | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ExitCode -value $line.ExitCode
        $tempreport | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value $line.ServiceName
        $tempreport | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ProcessId -value $line.ProcessId
        $tempreport | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name StartMode -value $line.StartMode
        $tempreport | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name State -value $line.State
        $tempreport | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Status -value $line.status
        $counter = $counter + 1
        write-host "Records  Looped: $counter"
        #Append
        $report += $tempreport
    } 
    write-output $report | ft

    # I WANT TO GET RID OF THIS LINE
    $data = import-csv .\ComputerServicesList.csv
    #perform Computer Count
    $uniqueComputerCount = ($data | Sort-Object ComputerName -Unique).Count
    write-host "Uniq computers counted: $uniqueComputerCount"        
    $RunningServices = $data | where-object {$_.State -eq "Running"} | Select ComputerName, ServiceName

    # List services that are shared.
    $SvcsCollapsed = $RunningServices | Group-Object ServiceName | where {$_.count -eq $uniqueComputerCount} | select Name 
    write-output $SvcsCollapsed      

}
import-csv .\ComputerServicesList.csv |  myTest3 | ft
```

My input CSV looks like:

```
    ComputerName    ServiceName    State
    Localhost       Svc1           Running
    Localhost       Svc2           Stopped
    Comp1           Svc1           Running
    Comp1           Svc2           Running
    Comp1           Svc3           Running
    Comp2           Svc1           Running
    Comp2           Svc3           Running
```

Comment: This looks almost the same as you last question. You should just go back and edit your previous one if you felt that it was not addressed correctly

Comment: I would really like to know why you are insisting to do it this way? The pipeline will process these items one at a time. You need `Group-Object` to work its magic on the whole entity.

Answer (score 0):

Is this more in line to what you were looking for in your previous question?

```
function myTest{
    [cmdletBinding()]
        param (
           [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                       ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                       ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,
                       HelpMessage="Input CSV file listing ComputerNames, Servicename, State")]
            $InputObject  
        )
    End{
        $uniqueComputerCount = ($input | Sort-Object ComputerName -Unique).Count
        Write-host "Unique Computers: $uniqueComputerCount"
        $input | Group-Object ServiceName | Where-Object{$_.Count -eq $uniqueComputerCount} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    }

}
```

Then the call would be:

```
Import-Csv c:\temp\data.log | myTest
```

`$input` contains the whole pipeline entity so that it can be processed at once as supposed to each individual line. Think you need PowerShell 3.0 for this to work as intended. For more reading on this subject you can look at [this blog](http://www.powertheshell.com/input_psv3/)

The explanation of the logic comes from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29083441/3829407). Once we figure out which question is better I can merge the two and remove one of them as this really looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt, you got me over the hump here with your suggestion of putting some code in the END{} section. This was the missing link that I was not understanding in PS up to now. The code also works with my other custom-cmdlet that creates the list eliminating the need to create the CSV, definately a plus ;-)

Working code for those that are interested:

```
    function myTest3 {
        [cmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                       ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                       ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,
                       HelpMessage="Input a CSV/Array with at least the following cols: ComputerName, ServiceName, State")]

            [array]$InputData 
        )

        BEGIN{
            # Setup code
            if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "nopipeline"){
                Write-Host "No pipeline input"
            }
        }
        PROCESS{
            $data += $InputData
        }
        END {
                #perform Computer Count
                $uniqueComputerCount = ($data | Sort-Object ComputerName -Unique).Count
                write-host "Uniq computers counted: $uniqueComputerCount"

                $RunningServices = $data | where-object {$_.State -eq "Running"} | Select ComputerName, ServiceName
```

# List services that are shared.
            $SvcsCollapsed = $RunningServices | Group-Object ServiceName | where {$_.count -eq $uniqueComputerCount} | select -ExpandProperty Name 
            write-output $SvcsCollapsed 
        }
}
#import-csv .\ComputerServicesList.csv |  myTest3 | ft
</code></pre>